# MiUI HTC OneX + ActionbarSherlock + Android Asset Studio Theme doesnt highlight on selected tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-assets

i used the example in ActionBarSherlock Sample project from http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html.

Then I applied the default theme to the app from http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-...rtiaryColor=F2F2F2,100&accentColor=33B5E5,100

This is the strange behavior. When I am checking the Activity with navigation as Tabs (ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS), the first and the last tab is not highlighting as soon as I apply the theme on MiUI ROM running on HTC One X

The same app is running fine on stock android, emulators, and every other configuration except MiUI

Can someone help?

To make life easy, I have uploaded the sample eclipse project export at http://bit.ly/Tu3xji

Following are the example of the problem:

[image: When first tab is selected]
[image: When second tab is selected]